# Errors while trying to build Unity app for VR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, virtual-reality

When I build or "build and run" the project I get three main errors. The project works because when I press play it does what it suppose to do in the game window. I'm trying to develop for the gearVr and Oculus which I selected in project settings.

I've looked at unity preferences made sure its using the correct SDK, JDK and NDK I even tried using the recommended settings but still couldn't upload anything to my device.

**ERROR 1**

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.  C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe
>   -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar"
>   org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m"
>   "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'.
>
>   > org.gradle.tooling.BuildException (no error message) ...

**ERROR 2**

> Build completed with a result of 'Failed' 0x00007FF6E6F9104C (Unity)
>   StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack 0x00007FF6E6F94501 (Unity)
>   StackWalker::ShowCallstack 0x00007FF6E56FDCC5 (Unity) GetStacktrace
>   0x00007FF6E79AF1D0 (Unity) DebugStringToFile 0x00007FF6E6FBFB49
>   (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log 0x00000200025704EB (Mono
>   JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log
>   (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
>   ...

**ERROR 3**

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 53 errors
>
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
>   (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194
>
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean
>   askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions)
>   [0x0007f] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97
>   0x00007FF6E6F9104C (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
>   0x00007FF6E6F94501 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
>   0x00007FF6E56FDCC5 (Unity) GetStacktrace 0x00007FF6E79AF1D0 (Unity)
>   DebugStringToFile 0x00007FF6E6FBFB49 (Unity)
>   DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log 0x00000200025704EB (Mono JIT Code)
>   (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log
>   (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
>   0x00000200025703AB (Mono JIT Code) [DebugLogHandler.cs:10]
>   UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat
>   (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[]) 
>   0x0000020002564691 (Mono JIT Code) [Logger.cs:61]
>   UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object) 
>   0x000002000257E7ED (Mono JIT Code) [Debug.bindings.cs:127]
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)  0x0000020039D5E5E3 (Mono JIT
>   Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:103]
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods
>   (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)  0x0000020039D377FB (Mono JIT Code)
>   [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:908]
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons
>   (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform)

Normally the apk will be uploaded to my phone asking me to place the device into the GearVR.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with Gradle. As a workaround you could try to switch from "gradle" to "internal" in the Build Window.